# Не могу получить объекты из сообщения телеграмм бота

Tags: java, telegram-bot, spring-boot

Делаю первого бота для телеграмма и столкнулся с проблемой. Не могу получить информацию об пользователе.
Снизу представлен код программы где я пытаюсь получить ссылки на объект юзер и контакт, но получаю только null. Хотя когда распечатываю message то вижу что у него есть все данные.

```
@Getter
@Value("${bot.username}")
private String botUsername;

@Getter
@Value("${bot.token}")
private String botToken;


@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    try {
        Message message = update.getMessage();
        if (message != null && message.hasText()) {
            SendMessage sendMessage = SendingMessage.defineMessageType(message.getText(), message);
            execute(sendMessage);
            System.out.println(update.getMessage().getForwardFrom());
            System.out.println(message.getContact());
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public String getBotUsername() {
    return botUsername;
}

@Override
public String getBotToken() {
    return botToken;
}
```

[image: Вывод на экран]

я понимаю что можно было бы просто прогнаться по этой строчке и вынудить оттуда всю инфу, но хотелось бы просто получить объект User

Comment: `getFrom` и `getForwardFrom` - разные вещи. Ну и `getContact` будет валидным только в том случае, если сообщение является контактом, которым корреспондент поделился с ботом. См. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message

Comment: `update.getMessage().getFrom()`